# Yii2 URL i8n not working

Tags: url, yii2

I'm using Yii2 and I have this configuration:

```
'urlManager' => [            
    'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
    'showScriptName' => false,            
    'rules' => [ 
        '<language:\w{2}>/<_c:\w+>/<_a:\w+>'=>'<_c>/<_a>',
    ],
],
```

Using this URL is OK:

http://localhost/webapp/it/site/index

But using this URL won't run:

http://localhost/webapp/it/site/folder/index

Answer (score 0):

Try to use https://github.com/codemix/yii2-localeurls

```
    // Override the urlManager component
    'urlManager' => [
        'class' => 'codemix\localeurls\UrlManager',

        // List all supported languages here
        // Make sure, you include your app's default language.
        'languages' => ['en', 'fr', 'de', 'es-*'],
    ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this line to rules. Maybe this works:

```
'<language:\w{2}>/<_m:\w+>/<_c:\w+>/<_a:\w+>'=>'<_m>/<_c>/<_a>',
```

But this is not universal way. You can use third-party extensions, if you want better solutions.